# Is the target of a spell at casting time the target of the spell for it's duration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

## Does the Target of a Spell Continue to be the Target?

Consider *dominate person* or *polymorph*.

A spell such as dominate person or polymorph is cast on a human. The human does not save. On the next round, is the human still considered the target of the spell?

Comment: To rephrase, *Is a spell continuously checking if it's affecting a legal target and is a spell dispelled or suppressed if the spell's target has become illegal after the spell was cast?* Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan that seems to be the actual problem behind the question. Perhaps the question should be restated with this problem in mind

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's the follow up question.  I decided they're separate issues.

Comment: I get the feeling there’s more behind this question than has been posted. Grosscol, what makes you wonder this?

Comment: (Y'know, were *Magic: The Gathering* never to've existed, I doubt anyone would consider concepts like *continuous targeting* and *it goes on the stack.* You never hear someone playing *Monopoly* say, "O, I rolled a 6? In response, I sell Boardwalk!")

Comment: @HeyICanChan I beg to differ. Building houses and hotels at "instant-speed" (between other people's turns) is very relevant to "high-level" monopoly play

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I'm not going to put words in his mouth, but it spawned from a long a meandering conversation on [chat] starting [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44930692#44930692).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes

Otherwise certain aspects of the spell would be meaningless:

> You can use your action to take total control of the target.

This explicitly refers to the humanoid affected by the spell as "target." If the creature ceased to be the target after the spell was cast, this ability would cease to function.