# What happens if modifications are made to the base entity while it is under the effects of a suppressed True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, antimagic-field

Posit the following situation:  A wizard has True Polymorphed a stick into, say, an adult Silver Dragon, and maintained it for the full hour.  He uses the thing as a mount, he's kept it happy with the idea, and all is well with the world.  An enemy catches them both in an antimagic field, and while he's picking himself up off the ground, breaks the stick in half and hands the two halves to two goblins, who start running in opposite directions.  What happens when the goblins in question clear the antimagic field?

Comment: Related: "[Do removed parts of a Druid's Wild Shape form persist after said Druid exits Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86653)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The original object ceases to be a valid target for the spell and the True Polymorph fails or is suppressed, depending on what the DM decides

From a previously answered question we know [the target of the spell remains the target of the spell for it's full duration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123728/is-the-target-of-a-spell-at-casting-time-the-target-of-the-spell-for-its-durati).

In this case, what has happened is that since the stick is broken the target has permanently become an invalid target for the spell (it's now two objects instead of one). In particular, neither sub-portion of the stick is the target of the spell, and thus the spell cannot become "un-suppressed" on either of the two halves of the stick.

You are essentially asking a more general version of [Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/is-a-spell-suppressed-or-removed-when-the-target-temporarily-becomes-invalid).

According to the accepted answer in that question, Jeremy Crawford has tweeted that:

> There's no rule governing what happens when a valid spell target temporarily becomes an invalid target. A good rule of thumb is that the spell is suppressed while the target is invalid.

So...it's up to the DM!

However, if the target is permanently invalid,  there isn't a hugely practical difference between the spell fizzling (ie it is effectively dispelled) and the spell being permanently suppressed...barring maybe the wizard attempting to mend the stick post battle.

Comment: Would this same problem arise if, for example, a small branch of the stick broke off, resulting in two objects of unequal size? If so, wouldn't essentially any object almost immediately become an invalid target due to minuscule wear and tear?

Comment: @Cacse while the object is under the effect of the True Polymorph there is no wear and tear that can happen (since it's magically transformed). But otherwise yes.

Comment: I meant while it's under the effect of the Antimagic Field. If you scratch the stick (thereby removing a minuscule amount of bark), is the stick now multiple different objects (one mostly-whole stick and many small particles of stick)?

Comment: @Cacse That's up to the DM. A stick broken in half and carried away by two separate creatures is definitely two objects. Where the line is between one object and two objects is up to the DM. I'd personally say that superficial wear and tear does not multiple objects make but another DM would rule differently.